# mystery operations

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

**1.**  3 __ 2 __ 36 __ 4  =  67

**2.**  3 __ 2 __ 36 __ 4  =  150

**3.**  3 __ 2 __ 36 __ 4  =  176

**4.**  3 __ 2 __ 36 __ 4  =  71

Fill in the blanks with mathematical operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication and division) and make the equation true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a set

> \begin{matrix} 3\,+\,(\,2\,\times\,(\,36\,-\,4\,)\,) & = 67 \\\\ (\,3\,\times\,2\,)\,+\,(\,36\,\times\,4\,) & = 150 \\\\ (\,(\,3\,+\,2\,)\,\times\,36\,)\,-\,4 & = 176 \\\\ 3\,+\,(\,(\,2\,\times\,36\,)\,-\,4\,) & = 71\end{matrix}

Answer (score 1):

1:

> $3+2\times(36-4)=67$

2:

> $3\times2+36\times4=150$

3: (added for completeness - thanks MCN)

> $(3+2)\times36-4=176$

4:

> $3+(2\times36)-4=71$